# Create Collection in Azure DocumentDB with Different Partition Mode

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

There are some sample code that create collection in azure documentDB using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB. However, I could not find information about how to create the collection with different partition mode using c#.

From the portal, there are 2 modes: Single Partition and Partitioned.

Can we use one or another when create collection using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have the SDK Version 1.6.0 or newer to support Document DB Partitioning.
Using the SDK you need to set the `OfferThroughput` value like shown below.

In this sample we set the `/deviceId` as the partition key.

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey);
await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = "db" });

// Collection for device telemetry. Here the JSON property deviceId will be used as the partition key to 
// spread across partitions. Configured for 10K RU/s throughput and an indexing policy that supports 
// sorting against any number or string property.
DocumentCollection myCollection = new DocumentCollection();
myCollection.Id = "coll";
myCollection.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/deviceId");

await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
    UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("db"),
    myCollection,
    new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 20000 });
```

Note:

In order to create partitioned collections, you must specify a `throughput` 
value of > 10,000 request units per second. Since throughput is in multiples of 100, this has to be 10,100 or higher.

So when your `OfferThroughput` is set to less than 20000 then your collection will be Single Partition.

Comment: Just a minor correction in Aram's response - I think you mean when throughput is set to less than 10000, then your collection has single partition.  More details are available at https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data.md