# Creating a Azure DocumentDB Partitioned Collection in node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create an Azure Document DB (cosmos DB) partitioned collection using node.

```
function _getOrCreateCollectionAsync(databaseUrl, collection){
var collectionUrl = `${databaseUrl}/colls/${collection.name}`,
    def = Q.defer();

    console.log("getting collection: " + collectionUrl);

    client.readCollection(collectionUrl, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code == 404) {
                console.log("collection " + collection.name + " not found... creating...");

                var colOptions = {};
                colOptions.offerThroughput = collection.azureOptions.offerThroughput || 10000; //default is 10k
                colOptions.partitionKey = ["/data"];
                // colOptions.partitionKey = ["data"];
                // colOptions.partitionKey = "/data";
                // colOptions.partitionKey = "data";

                var reqOptions = {
                    id : collection.name
                    //, partitionKey : ["/data"]
                }

                client.createCollection(databaseUrl, reqOptions, colOptions, (err, created) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        def.reject(err)
                    } else {
                        def.resolve(created);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                def.reject(err);
            }
        } else {
            def.resolve(result);
        }
    });

    return def.promise;
 }
```

(please ignore the code sloppiness, im still trying to get it to work)

when I run this I am getting this error

```
.......... working with collection: testCollection
getting collection: dbs/testDb/colls/testCollection
collection testCollection not found... creating...
{ code: 400,
  body: '{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\\"Errors\\":[\\"x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey header cannot be specified for this request\\"]}\\r\\nActivityId: (snip), Request URI: /apps/(snip)/services/(snip)/partitions/(snip)/replicas/(snip)"}',
  activityId: '(snip)' }
```

As you can see from above I have different options for defining the partition key and they all return the same result.

I also attempted to add it to the reqOptions by using this example [Create Collection in Azure DocumentDB with Different Partition Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884795/create-collection-in-azure-documentdb-with-different-partition-mode) as a guide (its in c#) and that indicated that he partition key needed to be part of the reqOptions object.  When I did that i got this error.

```
.......... working with collection: testCollection
getting collection: dbs/testDb/colls/testCollection
collection testCollection not found... creating...
{ code: 400,
  body: '{"code":"BadRequest","message":"The specified document collection is invalid.\\r\\nActivityId: (snip)"}',
  activityId: '(snip)' }
```

At this point I am at a loss and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value you're providing in `collection.azureOptions.offerThroughput`? Is it less than 2500?

Comment: i started at 400, but i read in the doc i posted, it had to be over 10,000.  I put 10,100 but I got another error saying that the value was too high. So for now I am using 10,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Cosmos DB REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-collection) stated, partition key must be specified as an object and put in the request body.

So, please change your code as below:

```
var colOptions = {};
colOptions.offerThroughput = collection.azureOptions.offerThroughput || 10000; //default is 10k

var reqOptions = {
    id: collection.name,
    partitionKey : { paths: ["/data"], kind: "Hash" }
}

client.createCollection(databaseUrl, reqOptions, colOptions, (err, created) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        def.reject(err)
    } else {
        def.resolve(created);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, i looked for 2 days for documentation that would help but I was focusing on node js docs... sometimes you need to just go to the source.  Let me test it out...